# Send messages from a bot to Microsoft Teams user in new chat thread instead of continuing the message in previous chat thread

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and sends a proactive message to a Microsoft Teams user. This would be a 1-1 conversation between bot and a user in Teams.

By default, Teams put all messages received via a bot through a single chat thread. This means a user receives all messages inside same single chat thread.

I need a functionality where bot sends message to a user in Teams in new chat thread instead of continuing the chat messages in previous chat thread.

Here I have attached a edited image where user in Teams receiving a message from a "MS Bot" in multiple chat threads.

[image]

Can we write a business logic where user in Teams receives message from a same bot in different thread as similar to above image?

Thanks

Comment: Currently it is not possible to have a new chat thread for a new message. Microsoft Teams handles and saves all the conversation and their history along with a specific app id on their end.The below answer by @Gousia-MSFT is completely valid.

Comment: @ranusharao Thanks! Yeah it looks currently not possible, but i was looking for such feature to handle some business requirements.

Comment: I actually tried to do the same thing using multiparty chats and having the bot set a subject, but this isn't possible right now.  Bots can't create group chats, and only group chats can set a conversation subject.

Answer (score 1):

@jayanta Every app in Microsoft teams has a app id and messages sent to that app will all be listed in a single chat thread. One bot cannot create different chat threads for different messages.